# What is the difference between android and droid?

Tags: android

What is the difference between android and droid?

Does [Google own Android](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-ultimate-weather-app/hjdnakgakbbofjpdcogjocponodcgiai)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Droid

Comment: some days, the only answer is LMGTFY...  http://lmgtfy.com/?q=What+is+the+difference+between+android+and+droid%3F

Answer (score 3):

Reference [Are Android and Droid the Same Thing?](https://www.lookout.com/resources/know-your-mobile/android-vs-droid)

> **What is Android?**
>
> It’s a Linux-based operating system released by Google in 2008 to
>   compete with Apple’s iOS. Like the engine to the sports car, Android
>   is what separates mobile devices from absurdly expensive paper
>   weights. It manages the memory, processes, software and hardware on
>   your phone or tablet.
>
> **What is Droid?**
>
> It’s Verizon’s most popular line of smartphones distributed by
>   manufacturers Motorola, HTC, and Samsung. The American carrier
>   actually had to purchase licensing rights for the term from Star Wars
>   director George Lucas, who coined it way back when Luke was still
>   looking for his father. The Droid brand  exclusively runs the Android
>   OS, which is where the name mix-up stems from. That said, you better
>   believe the marketeers over at Verizon are having a field day with the
>   crossover.